# Saving large matrix in a file in Python

Tags: python, file, matrix

I am producing a large matrix in python from a loop function, so i want to save it in a file for further using, to do this i used this following where bxx is my matrix of dimension (3324, 1, 24464):

```
#write matrix to file
import numpy
my_matrix = bxx
numpy.savetxt('matrix.txt', my_matrix, delimiter = ',')

#read file into a matrix
import numpy
my_matrix = numpy.loadtxt(open("matrix.txt","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=0)
```

I got the error massage :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11628\2774506594.py in <module>
      6 #read file into a matrix
      7 import numpy
----> 8 my_matrix = numpy.loadtxt(open("matrix.txt","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=0)

~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows, like)
   1148         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1149             if X is None:
-> 1150                 X = np.array(x, dtype)
   1151             else:
   1152                 nshape = list(X.shape)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 620. MiB for an array with shape (3324, 1, 24464) and data type float64
```

Comment: Where does this error occur?

Comment: @ScottHunter when i run the code in Pycharm python project

Comment: If `bxx` is a numpy array, I'd recommend just using NumPy's [`save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) functions, which will store and read the array from a binary file rather than a text file. This will save space on disk, although it probably won't help the memory error when loading the file.